# Equivalent to vlookup for strings in Python?

Tags: python, lookup

Is there a way to search for a substring in a larger string, and then return a different substring x places left or right of the original substring?
I want to look through a string like "blahblahlink:"www.example.com"blahblah for the string "link:" and return the subsequent url.
Thanks!
Python 3, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use regular expressions. There is module called **re** in python for that.

Comment: I didn't know about these and they look promising or at least very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pure Python solution would be to use `index` which tells you where in the string the first match occurs, then use the `[start:end]` slicing notation to select the string from that point:

```
"blahblahlink:www.example.comblahblah".index("link")
# returns 8

i = "blahblahlink:www.example.comblahblah".index("link")
"blahblahlink:www.example.comblahblah"[i+5:i+20]
# returns 'www.example.com'
```